# Concourse Pipelines Integration with Pivotal Tracker

Tags: concourse, pivotaltracker

Is there a way to trigger the pipelines from Pivotal Tracker when click on "finish" or "deliver" or "Accept" button status in the Pivotal Tracker

Answer (score 1):

There is a [resource for Pivotal Tracker](https://github.com/concourse/tracker-resource) but it only triggers on stories that are linked in recent git commits.

If that's not your case, you can use [`webhook_token`](https://concourse-ci.org/resources.html#resource-webhook-token) to trigger the resource check and use this webhook in [Pivotal Tracker](https://www.pivotaltracker.com/help/articles/activity_webhook/), the problem there is, it's being called on all activities. You'll need some intermediate layer like [Zapier](https://zapier.com) (or anything that allows you to run your own code) to filter those events only to pass `story_update_activity` event.

Comment: Thanks a lot Suda... Let me check and do the sample program. I will update you...

Comment: Is there any option to call Zapier toConcourse Jobs or Developer has to write the complete code to invoke particular job from Zapier?  And also i heard that there is no REST API for Concourse Jobs to invoke the jobs from outside of the concourse server or  using FLY command line.